# SelectedValue of RadioButtonList control through a WebBrowser control in C# ASP .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, automated-tests, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to do very simple automation testing through a WebBrowser control.  There are 2 sides: the application side that has untouchable code, and the testing side, which I'm generating to do a click-through automation.

The problem is that the radio buttons are created in the code behind of the web page control I'm trying to test - they are part of a RadioButtonList control (using RBL.Items.Insert..)  On top of that, the RadioButtonList has a event handler OnSelectedIndexChanged that gets the SelectedValue.
I'm able to find the code-behind generated radio buttons through the WebBrowser control and set the following:

```
HtmlElement subjectRadioButton = browser.Document.GetElementById("...");
if (subjectRadioButton != null)
{
    subjectRadioButton.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

The debugger shows I'm getting in the code.  Also, if you don't do anything else, you can see the item checked visually.  On the other side, the page I am testing, however, once a postback happens, it gets into the event handler.  The event handler has the following code that's breaking:

```
int.Parse(rblSubject.SelectedValue);
```

The rblSubject.SelectedValue, is the empty string and never populated, no matter how I try to invoke the subjectRadioButton, which is an item that's part of the RadioButtonList.  I even tried through javascript and confirmed checked=true.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the radio buttons themselves not synching with the RadioButtonList, since it's dynamically created in the code behind.  What's even more odd is that an all manual test works fine.  It's just doing the automated one fails.  I also noticed that if I were to simply set InvokeMember("click"), there is no error (no postback happens).  It does look checked though.  When I then perform InvokeMember("click") on a link or a button on the page, a post-back happens, the event handler fires and I get the parsing error.  Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is the code on the app side I'm testing - the one I can't modify, that initializes the RadioButtonList rblSubject.

```
rblSubject.Items.Clear();
ListItem item;
if (obj <= 0)
{
    item = new ListItem(GetObject("BillingIssue").ToString(), ((int)SubjectTypeEnum.BillingQuestion).ToString());
    rblSubject.Items.Insert(0, item);
    item = new ListItem(GetObject("ChangeNote").ToString(), ((int)SubjectTypeEnum.ChangeOfInformation).ToString());
    rblSubject.Items.Insert(1, item);
    item = new ListItem(GetObject("OtherAdmin").ToString(), ((int)SubjectTypeEnum.AdminNote).ToString());
    rblSubject.Items.Insert(2, item);
}
```

Comment: Could you paste where you are creating these dynamic radiobuttons? People usually forget to wire them back to the page, that's why page processing don't bind them to the view state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I edited it to include the code behind for the radio button list initialization.  Is that's what's causing the issue?

Comment: Maybe. Where (in which method) is that code? Page_Load, Page_Init...?

Comment: Ok this is odd.  It's a public method and is being called in OnInit as well as the parent control Page_Load.  Maybe that's the source of the error.  I will have to debug that.  Also, I talked to another person as well and he mentioned that the event is fired before the radiobutton gets assigned a value.

Comment: Try moving this method call to the PreInit handler of the page, and only there. Afterwards, the page will bind the viewstate to its objects, and then your radio will receive its value. The event only get handled after the whole page lifecycle, it will work.